# Star Trek Voyager: Why does the Main Computer act less intelligent than a hologram?

Tags: star-trek

Holograms, whether designed to be sentient (To learn and adapt) or as simple pre-designed characters have shown to be capable of rivaling any Human when it came to realism. The Doctor is a late-case of this ingenuity, a relitively new technology at the time -- But Holograms themselves were not.

The Voyagers computer is stiff, it acts too artificial. When it doesn't understand a question it gives off the impression of being unintelligent, compared to a holodeck character who'd likely be capable of discerning what the user was requesting of it fairly quickly.

I could understand this design choice for a stable AI that uses little processing power...

But if the above were a non-issue, I don't understand the design choice of an AI that feels long outdated, despite being state of the art. Can anyone explain this to my satisfaction?

*Edit: Long overdue edit. This was not a duplicate of the Question linked, but rather a question as to why the AI acts (Verbally) less intelligent than it is. The link offered that claims this is a duplicate is towards the Federation's lack of using True Artificial Intelligence on their computers (Which is a good move, see most interactions with Sentient AI's and those who think they're Sentient)
Mine was towards the lack of User Friendliness. To give the Computer a slight Personality reminiscent of that of a Holodeck Program would make it more user-friendly, capable of responding in other ways outside of "Please restate the Question" which is stiff and gives off the impression of being a simple program.
"I am unable to decipher the phenomenon we are witnessing, Captain."
Versus
"Unknown."*

Comment: The AI is variably intelligent throughout ST and is being pointed out by the Mission Log Podcast a number of times where the Computer is smart enough to determine x, like whether or not somone is going to walk through a door, but at other times very dumb.

Comment: “I could understand this design choice for a stable AI that uses little processing power... But if the above were a non-issue” — but it’s not. See the Moriarty episodes of *The Next Generation* for how holodeck AIs can be bad, and *Voyager’s* [‘Author, Author’(http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Author,_Author_(episode)) for some discussion of AIs rights.

Comment: See recent edit.